# exec command "who": Broken Pipe && "ps":bad namelist

Tags: pipe, freebsd

I typed "who" under Freebsd4.5, the information showed as below:

stdout: Broken pipe
......
but showed "test             ttyp0   Sep 20 20:39   (192.X.X.8)"last line.

and exec command ps, it returns "ps:bad namelist".

Is there any way to trace the problem? Any help is ok~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as ps:bad namelist,
there is a way to solve it.
following next steps:

```
# cd /dev
# rm null
# mknod null c 2 2
# chmod 666 null
```

as "who" and uptime error ,please check /var/run/utmp to see whether there's some garbage information.